# Select column with row number concatenated in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and want to select a column in a table with the row number concatenated to the column value in the result set.

For example:

```
DemoField
---------
Apple
Ball
Cat
```

Should return this result set:

```
DemoField
---------
Row1 Apple
Row2 Ball
Row3 Cat
```

I went through a few similar questions where `ROW_NUMBER()` is used, but I find that it is selected as a separate column and not concatenated to an existing column being returned.

When I try to concatenate the `ROW_NUMBER()` to the column, I get an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You want Row1, Row2, Row3 as rows in one column? Or is that a text "Row1 Apple"

Comment: "Row1 Apple" it is just one column

Comment: Well, show us ***HOW*** you try to concat the two pieces of information! Since `ROW_NUMBER()` returns an `INT`, you would have to *at least* use a `CAST(ROW_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10))` or something similar, before concatenating with a string value from the other column ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you're trying to add a number to a string.  You have to `CAST` your row_number as a VARCHAR i.e.

```
'Row' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DemoField) AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 6):

If 2012+ you can use **concat()**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([DemoField] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Apple')
,('Ball')
,('Cat')

Select concat('Row',Row_Number() over(Order By DemoField),' ',DemoField)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)
Row1 Apple
Row2 Ball
Row3 Cat
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just basic ROW_NUMBER with some concatenation. Seems the desired output is pretty strange but the concept is simple.

```
select DemoField
from
(
    select DemoField = 'Row' + convert(varchar(4), ROW_NUMBER() over (order by DemoField)) + ' ' + DemoField
    from YourTable
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get row number concatenated to any column, check the other answers. But IMO, that is really odd.

If you want to get row number in a separate column,

you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some_column) as RowNumber FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following -

```
SELECT CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR)+' '+CAST(ColName AS NVARCHAR) 
  FROM tb_Table
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem sorry? What is the ID field?

Comment: So I don't know what the names of your columns are. It's just an example. ID would be Row1, Row2, Row3 etc, so change ID to whatever you named the column and then ColName would be Apple, Ball, Cat etc. So replace colName with your column name. Then obviously replace tb_Table with your table name. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CONCAT() as well as USE CAST() for the row number to convert it to character

```
SELECT CONCAT('Row',CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY demofield) AS VARCHAR),' ', demofield)
```